# How to get value from active profile in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Using spring boot I set value in .properties file and want that value to be used in my service class.
Is there any way to get value from active profile and use it in service class?

Here is my sample code in `.properties` file

```
    spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.enabled= true
    spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.initial-interval= 10s
    spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts= 2
    spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-interval= 30s
    spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.multiplier= 2
```

I want to get **.max-attempts= 2** in my service class

Here is the method of service class where I want to max-attempts value.

```java
    public boolean validateRetryAttempts(EmailDto email)
        {

            @Value("${spring.profiles.active:unknown"
            int maxAttempt = 2;
            
            if (!maxRetryAttempts.containsKey(email.getEmail())) {
                maxRetryAttempts.put(email.getEmail(), 1);
                
            } else {
                
                if ((maxRetryAttempts.get(email.getEmail())+1)>=maxAttempt) {
                    maxRetryAttempts.put(email.getEmail(), maxRetryAttempts.get(email.getEmail())+1);
                    return true;
                } else
                    maxRetryAttempts.put(email.getEmail(), maxRetryAttempts.get(email.getEmail())+1);
            }
            
            return false;
            
        }
```

I have tried `@Value("${spring.profiles.active: unknown")` in the method but it gives disallowed location error.

Comment: Can you please add the complete code, including where you put the `@Value`? Thanks!

Comment: Sure. I am using it in Service class method.

Comment: I have edited in my question please review it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't place `@Value` inside a method. Valid locations are:

- Field
- Method
- Parameter
- Annotation

Having written this, please place it as a Service property:

```java
@Service
public class Service {

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts}")
    private int maxAttempt;

    public boolean validateRetryAttempts(EmailDto email){
  
        if (!maxRetryAttempts.containsKey(email.getEmail())) {
            maxRetryAttempts.put(email.getEmail(), 1);
        } else {
            
            if ((maxRetryAttempts.get(email.getEmail())+1)>=maxAttempt) {
                maxRetryAttempts.put(email.getEmail(), maxRetryAttempts.get(email.getEmail())+1);
                return true;
            } else
                maxRetryAttempts.put(email.getEmail(), maxRetryAttempts.get(email.getEmail())+1);
        }
        
        return false;  
    }

}
```

Comment: In method I manually initialized maxAttempt but I want its value which I set in .properties file in spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts= 2.

Comment: Is there any way to set maxAttempt from .properties file?

Comment: Yes, I've just edited my answer. Please check it ;)

Comment: I have edited the code but maxAttempt is not set to 2, it shows 0 in debugging.

Comment: Can you please add to your question the complete Service class? Thanks!

Comment: I am using this method in common service class and calling it from my service class and it is too lengthy to share it.

Comment: Then we can only guess. My bet is that the service class where you have `@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts}")` is not a Spring-managed bean and thus nothing is injected. Try to put at least the service class definition in your question.